# Why does SBT give me a type a type mismatch error?

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm trying the following setting

```
unmanagedClasspath  += file("/home/...")
```

And am getting the following error

```
error: type mismatch;
 found   : sbt.package.File
 required: sbt.Attributed[java.io.File]
```

What is the syntax for sbt.Attributed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Attributed.blank(...)` to wrap the file inside an attributed instance. You should also provide the context (for instance `Runtime`):

```
unmanagedClasspath in Runtime += Attributed.blank( file("/home/...") )
```